# CI/CD for multi-tenant application with single repository but multiple clients

Tags: github, jenkins, automation, multi-tenant, cicd

I have a database-driven application with a single code base configured for multiple clients using the database setting and config files.
The main code base consists of common/core code/files that are being used by all the clients and some client-specific code/files. Both types of files are in different folders of the same repository.

We have been planning to integrate CI/CD using GitHub and Jenkins. I am new to Jenkins.

In GitHub, we have a single repository that contains all the code/files. I want to use Jenkins to deploy to different client environments but make sure that only files related to a specific client should be deployed to that client environment.

What could be the best way or possible solutions for this?

Edit: Basically I want to deploy specific files that are client related to specific client environments.

Any and all suggestions would be highly appreciated.